# Formula to compare if string numbers are equal in one column row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a column in Excel called "Positions".
 The column can have string numbers like this

Positions

1-5

1-7

1-7

1-8

1-89

2-1

2-12

2-2

2-3

.....
N-N.. the first number is referencing the page number and the second number i.e. after the "-" is referencing the page position.

The page is divided into 9 positions starting from left to right just like this:

1  2  3

4  5  6

7  8  9

So when you have the number 1-8 in the position column it means:

Page 1

1  2  3

4  5  6

7 (8) 9

And when you have the number 2-12 in the position column it means:

Page 2

(1)  (2)  3

4    5   6

7    8   9

Now that's how it is designed but what I want modify is only in the Position column when I have a set of positions like mentioned before

Positions

1-5

1-7

1-7

1-8

1-89

2-1

2-12

2-2

2-3

.....

then I need a formula to notify me in some way that position 1-8 and 1-89 will overlap and position 2-1, 2-12 and 2-2 will also overlap. And of course position 1-7 and 1-7 will fully overlap therefore this should also notify the user. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP added the `VBA` tag; please try this procedure.
It splits a `Position` in its corresponding `3 pieces` comparing them against all other `Positions` in the list.
It assumes the `Positions` list starts at `B2` and list the comparison results in column `C`.

```
'These Options declaration always go at the top of the module, class, etc. 
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Get_Overlap()
Const kFlag As String = "Overlapping"   'Change as required
Dim rData As Range, aData As Variant, aResults() As String, sResult As String
Dim lA As Long, sAvalue As String, iAp As Integer, bA1 As Byte, bA2 As Byte
Dim lB As Long, sBvalue As String, iBp As Integer, bB1 As Byte, bB2 As Byte

    Rem Sets Data Range & Arrays
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TEST").Columns("B")   'Change as required
        Set rData = Range(.Cells(2), .Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    aData = rData.Value2
    aData = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aData)
    rData.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    ReDim Preserve aResults(UBound(aData))

    For lA = 1 To UBound(aData)

        Rem Initialize & Set Item A Values
        sAvalue = Empty: sAvalue = aData(lA)
        iAp = 0: iAp = Left(sAvalue, 1)
        bA1 = 0: bA1 = Mid(sAvalue, 3, 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        bA2 = 0: bA2 = Mid(sAvalue, 4, 1)
        On Error GoTo 0

        For lB = lA + 1 To UBound(aData)

            Rem Initialize & Set Item B Values
            sBvalue = Empty: sBvalue = aData(lB)
            iBp = 0: iBp = Left(sBvalue, 1)
            bB1 = 0: bB1 = Mid(sBvalue, 3, 1)
            On Error Resume Next
            bB2 = 0: bB2 = Mid(sBvalue, 4, 1)
            On Error GoTo 0

            Rem Initialize Comparison Result
            sResult = Empty

            Rem Compare Items & Values
            Select Case True
            Case sAvalue = sBvalue
                sResult = kFlag

            Case iAp = iBp
                Select Case True
                Case bA2 = 0 And bB2 = 0
                    If (bA1 = bB1) Then sResult = kFlag

                Case bA2 = 0
                    If bA1 >= bB1 And bA1 <= bB2 Then sResult = kFlag

                Case bB2 = 0
                    If bB1 >= bA1 And bB1 <= bA2 Then sResult = kFlag

                Case Else
                    If bA1 >= bB1 And bA1 <= bB2 Then
                        sResult = kFlag
                    ElseIf bA2 >= bB1 And bA2 <= bB2 Then
                        sResult = kFlag
                    ElseIf bB1 >= bA1 And bB1 <= bA2 Then
                        sResult = kFlag
                    ElseIf bB2 >= bA1 And bB2 <= bA2 Then
                        sResult = kFlag
                    End If

            End Select: End Select

            Rem Add Results into Array
            If sResult <> Empty Then
                aResults(lA) = sResult
                aResults(lB) = sResult
            End If

    Next: Next

    Rem Enter Comparison Results
    'Results will be posted one column to the right of where the List
    'This is done by the use of "rData.Offset(0,1)"
    rData.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(aResults)

    End Sub
```

Suggest to read the following pages to gain a deeper understanding of the resources used:

[Option keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278518(v=office.15).aspx), 
[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), 
[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx), 
[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), 
[WorksheetFunction Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx),
[For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251601.aspx),
[Select Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278665.aspx),
[If...Then...Else Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251599.aspx), 
[On Error Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251688.aspx), 
[Range.Offset Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! where in the code should I define column c? I guess I need a new column in the Excelsheet that have the Position column?  Option Explicit nad Option Base 1 were is those going to be?

Comment: If this solves your problem please select\tag it as your answer

Comment: 1.- The code post the results in the column to the right of where the List, i.e. The List is in B then results are posted in C. This is done by the line `rData.Offset(0,1)`. 2.- Don't understand what are you referring to. 3.- The Options declarations always go at the top of the module, class, etc. *(see edit in the answer)*

Comment: I marked this answer is useful and thats because I am genererally very fast to give credit, and when I see that you have made a quite effort I gaved you the credit for it. However is still doesnt solved the problem. And thanks for the references I will look at it but still no time to solve the problem if that even will solve the problem. Is it possible to send you the code in some way to get help with it, the whole code is not that big. (Only 700 lines)

Comment: Have you run the code?, what cases are not identified by the code? Would you explain what is still missing. I ran the test with your sample data and all overlaps where flagged.

Comment: Ok now it worked, nice! How can I enbedd a message box istead of Overlapping text?

Comment: Insert it in the section `Rem Add Results into Array`

Comment: Not like this I guess? 
Rem Add Results into Array
            `If sResult <> Empty Then
                aResults(lA) = sResult
                aResults(lB) = sResult
                MsgBox (sResult)
            End If`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126828/discussion-between-henrik-and-eem).

Comment: so if the code worked, why have not you tag the answer?